# Alternatives in negative look-behind

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm looking to match a string that is not preceded by a `"]: "` or a `"("`. First, I tried using the look-behind syntax for just one of the criteria at a time and it works:

```
/(?<!\]: )\b(.+)/i

/(?<!\()\b(.+)/i
```

Then when I try to combine both criteria using the or syntax in the look-behind, it breaks:

```
/(?<!(\]: |\())\b(.+)/i
```

I get an error saying:

```
RegexpError: invalid pattern in look-behind
```

Is there anything like `Regexp.union` that requires a string to match all the expressions? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Anything wrong with `(?<!\()(?<!\]: )\b(.+)`?

Comment: @Rawing - Thanks! It think it's working but I'll need to add some more tests to confirm. I didn't know look-behinds can be chained but it makes total sense.

Comment: @Rawing - you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: You should provide sample text demonstrating what you're trying to match, instead of relying on people imagining what it could be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two consecutive lookbehinds like this:

```
(?<!\()(?<!\]: )\b(.+)
```

Comment: I like this answer because it is more readable to me being able to chain them.

Answer (score 0):

From [Oniguruma manual](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/doc/RE.txt):

```
(?<=subexp)        look-behind
(?<!subexp)        negative look-behind

                     Subexp of look-behind must be fixed character length.
                     [D]ifferent character length is allowed in top level
                     alternatives only.
                     ex. (?<=a|bc) is OK. (?<=aaa(?:b|cd)) is not allowed.

                     In negative-look-behind, captured group isn't allowed, 
                     but shy group(?:) is allowed.
```

So just replace the captured group by a shy group:

```
/(?<!(?:\]: |\())\b(.+)/i
```

Comment: I find nothing wrong with this answer. Why the downvote?